# Prevent rmarkdown params to convert string input to numeric

Tags: r, bash, r-markdown, parameters

first question here :),

I've been trying to build a [parametrized rmarkdown report](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html#passing_parameters) with an environmental variable as an input, as suggested in the rmarkdown documentation. However, the environmental variable I'm assigning (as character) is being evaluated as numeric (rather than as character).

Here's a reproducible example, composed of 2 files: A bash script `test.sh` which calls a report `test-report.Rmd` to generate the desired output.

Here's the code of `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
echo "Analysis for" $now
R -e "rmarkdown::render('test-report.Rmd', params = list(latest_update = as.character($now)))"
```

As you can observe in the figure below, the environmental variable I'm assigning to `latest_update` is being evaluated as numeric (rather than as character). I'm expecting to see `2016-04-12` instead of `2000` as the value of `params$latest_update`

[image: html output of test-report.Rmd]

here's the code for my `test-report.Rmd`:

````
---
title: "Test Report"
author: "test author"
fontsize: 8pt
output:
  html_document
params:
  latest_update:
    value: !r as.character("2016-04-12")
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, results = 'asis')
```

```{r params}
cat("# here are some params!")
cat("\n\n")
cat("param value: ")
cat(params$latest_update)
cat("\n\n")
```
````

To isolate the issue even further, I tried to input a character string (instead of an environmental variable to `rmarkdown::render`, but i'm still getting the same result described above.

```
R -e "rmarkdown::render('test-report.Rmd', params = list(latest_update = as.character("2016-04-12")))
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with single quotes ? What about escaping the `-`'s ?

Comment: single quotes did it!  `R -e "rmarkdown::render('reports/test-report.Rmd', params = list(latest_update = '$now'))"`. Let me know if you want to add that as an answer, thank you @123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @123's comment, the solution was simply escaping the *environmental variable*.

By replacing this line in my `test.sh`

```
R -e "rmarkdown::render('test-report.Rmd', params = list(latest_update = '$now'))"
```

I obtain the desired output of `2016-04-12` (and thus, the unaltered string value).

(thanks **123**!)